# Получить значения полей объекта, переданного через TValue

Tags: delphi, rtti

Как можно исследовать объект, который должен передаваться в метод с помощью Rtti? Например я хочу получить значения всех полей объекта. Пример как я пробую:

```
type
  TSimple = Class
    I: Integer;
    S: String;
  end;
    ////////////////
function TRttiSearch.CheckObject(AValue: TValue; const ARequest: String): Boolean;
var
  rC: TRttiContext;
  rT: TRttiType;
  rF: TRttiField;
  LValue: TValue;
begin
  Result := False;
  AValue.AsType<TSimple>.I := 10;
  AValue.AsType<TSimple>.S := '15';
  rC := TRttiContext.Create;
  try
{1} rT := rC.GetType(AValue.TypeInfo); // Информация о типе
    Log.d(rT.QualifiedName); //
    for rF in rT.GetFields do // Перебираем поля объекта
    begin
{2}  LValue := rF.GetValue(AValue.GetReferenceToRawData); // Пытаемся получить значение поля
      Log.d('%S = ''%S''', [rF.ToString, LValue.AsVariant]); //
      Result := CheckTValue(LValue, ARequest);
      if Result then
        Break;
    end;
  finally
    rC.Free;
  end;
end;
```

{1} - тип определяется правильно. Но в {2} - возвращает значения по-умолчанию. Вот что в логе:

> Debug Output: RareUtils.RttiSearch.TSimple Process Test.exe (5312)
>
> Debug Output: I: Integer @ 04 = '0' Process Test.exe (5312) Debug
>
> Output: S: string @ 08 = '' Process Test.exe (5312)

Как я понимаю нужно передавать не `AValue.GetReferenceToRawData`, а что-то другое. Но что именно?

Comment: определяйте тип поля `case value.Kind of  tkInteger : ...` (`TValue.Kind`) и т.п. и выводите соответственно. `GetValue` метод должен получать указатель на экземпляр объекта. Есть у вас `x : TTest` с полем `FField`, создали экземпляр этого `x`, потом получили экземляр `var f : TRttiField` для вашего `FField`, и что бы вернуть значение поля для конкретного объекта надо `f.getValue(x)` сделать.

Comment: напишите лучше, что вы вообще хотите сделать?

Comment: @teran Поиск по TArray<T>

Comment: В AValue точно будет объект. Определение типа уже сделал. Как мне подсказали для моего случая достаточно заменить 
`LValue := rF.GetValue(AValue.GetReferenceToRawData); `
на
`LValue := rF.GetValue(AValue.AsObject); `

Comment: да, именно так. `asObject`

Answer (score 1):

Нужно объявить переменную   `RawDataPointer: Pointer`, затем получить указатель `AValue.ExtractRawData(RawDataPointer);` и в `GetValue` использовать уже `RawDataPointer`

Пример:

```
var
  ...
  RawDataPointer: Pointer;
  ...
begin
  ...
  AValue.ExtractRawData(RawDataPointer);
  LValue := rF.GetValue(RawDataPointer); // Пытаемся получить значение поля
  ...
end;
```

Comment: `AValue.ExtractRawData(RawDataPointer);`- тут AV